# Mouse movement in Windows like Mac

Tags: mac, windows, mouse

While most people seem to want the Windows mouse movement on their Mac, I'd like it the other way around! Basically just remove the mouse acceleration on Windows.

Ideas, anyone?

P.S. I posted this in the Apple section because I would get annihilated by Windows fanboys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149228

But good luck anyway, in this Mac crowd! :)